# Selenium pageFactory NullPointerException for driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Selenium pageFactory `NullPointerException`. Any help will be appreciated. It works for the login of `setUp()`, but after that driver comes up null.

```
public class TestBase {

    public WebDriver driver;
    String url = PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("autUrl");

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
        System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/driver/chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        return driver;
    }

    public void getUrl(String url) {
        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public void init() {
        getDriver();
        getUrl(url);
    }
}



public class LogInPage extends TestBase {
    WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(id = "loginEmail")public WebElement userName_field;
    @FindBy(name = "password")public WebElement password_field;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='main-content']/aside/div/form/input[2]")public WebElement SignMeIn_btn;

    public LogInPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    // Login
    public void logIn(String userName, String password) {
        userName_field.sendKeys(userName);
        password_field.sendKeys(password);
        SignMeIn_btn.click();
    }

}


   public class LogIn extends TestBase {

    LogInPage logInPage;

    private String user = PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("user");
    private String password = PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("password");



    public LogIn(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }


    public void setUp(){
        init();
    }


    public void logIn(){
        logInPage = new LogInPage(driver);
        logInPage.logIn(user, password);
    }

}

public class PortalsPage extends TestBase {

    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(id = "loginEmail") public WebElement userName_field;
    @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='tabDetail']") public WebElement tenantPage_li;
    @FindBy(id="tabDetail") public WebElement ownerPage_li;
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(@href,'tenant.action')]") public WebElement tenantPortal_link;
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(@href,'owner.action')]") public WebElement ownerPortal_link;

    public PortalsPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }


    public void goToPortals(){      
        userName_field.sendKeys("a");
        tenantPage_li.click();
    }

}

public class Portals extends TestBase {
    PortalsPage portals;
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
        LogIn login = new LogIn(driver);
        login.setUp();
        login.logIn();

    }

    @Test
    public void goToPortal(){
        portals = new PortalsPage(driver);
        portals.goToPortals();
    }
}
```

Following exception I got:

> FAILED: goToPortal java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.sendKeys(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.demo.pages.PortalsPage.goToPortals(PortalsPage.java:30)   at
>   com.demo.control.Portals.goToPortal(Portals.java:28)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

Comment: what does TestBase look like? Why do all the classes extend it and they each have their own driver instance except for Login?

Comment: Basically I want to get the driver's instance from TestBase. I was trying to with or without the local class instance in the Portals class. Tried both ways and got the same result.

Comment: I have added the TestBase class code as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach seems to be a bit convoluted. But without delving into the details of what other approach you can use to fix your overall design, here's a cleaned up version of your code, that should work.

The idea here is that you only need page classes (the ones that end with `*Page` which represent a particular page, and exposes some business functions that can be executed on that particular page) and test classes, with the test class themselves extending from your `TestBase`

So here are the classes

**LoginPage.java**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class LogInPage {
    @FindBy(id = "loginEmail")
    private WebElement userNameTextField;
    @FindBy(name = "password")
    private WebElement passwordTextField;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='main-content']/aside/div/form/input[2]")
    private WebElement signInButton;

    public LogInPage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void logIn(String userName, String password) {
        userNameTextField.sendKeys(userName);
        passwordTextField.sendKeys(password);
        signInButton.click();
    }

}
```

**PortalsPage.java**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class PortalsPage {
    @FindBy(id = "loginEmail")
    private WebElement usernameTextField;
    @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='tabDetail']")
    private WebElement tenantPage;
    @FindBy(id = "tabDetail")
    private WebElement ownerPage;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(@href,'tenant.action')]")
    private WebElement tenantPortalLink;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(@href,'owner.action')]")
    private WebElement ownerPortalLink;


    public PortalsPage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void goToPortals() {
        usernameTextField.sendKeys("a");
        tenantPage.click();
    }
}
```

**TestBase.java**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestBase {
    private WebDriver driver;

    protected WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver != null) {
            return driver;
        }
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/driver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        return driver;
    }

    public void getUrl(String url) {
        getDriver().get(url);
        getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

**PortalsTest.java**

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class PortalsTest extends TestBase {
    private PortalsPage portals;
    private String user = PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("user");
    private String password = PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("password");
    private String url = PropertiesFile.readPropertiesFile("autUrl");


    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        LogInPage login = new LogInPage(getDriver());
        getUrl(url);
        login.logIn(user, password);
    }

    @Test
    public void goToPortal() {
        portals = new PortalsPage(getDriver());
        portals.goToPortals();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks Krishnan. Appreciate your feedback regarding the design as well.